# A quick clarification of Hawking Radiation

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation

Good Morning,

I have read the other posts on Hawking Radiation, and did not want to post a question to an older post...  I just want a quick clarification of a point.

Can you please clarify is this is correct for me?  "From reading the other posts, a BH loses mass, not because it is absorbing an anti-particle or a particle with a negative energy, it is losing mass because the energy to create the "real" particle pair from virtual particles takes some energy from the BH.  When one escapes, it is taking 1/2 of this energy (more or less) from the BH."

Is my understanding correct?

As a follow up, how much energy is a solar mass BH losing per second doing this?  Has anyone ever calculated how much energy a BH loses / second?  or is this a ridiculous question?

Thanks

Comment: yes, the energy is taken from the black hole in order for virtual to  become real. see here my analogy https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/451618/

Comment: The virtual particle story of Hawking radiation is a simplification. Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/252236/123208 You may enjoy playing with the [Hawking radiation calculator](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator).

Comment: FWIW, a 1 solar mass BH is a bit too small to form, the smallest are around 3 $M_\odot$. And the Hawking radiation temperature of such BHs is tiny, the CMB is much hotter, so they receive a lot more energy than they can radiate.

Comment: @PM2Ring - what would be the smallest BH that would be hotter than the CMB?

Comment: The Hawking radiation calculator can tell you that. Just plug in 2.725 K as the temperature. The answer is 0.00753950 Earth masses.

Comment: @PM2Ring - the question then becomes, if they are absorbing more from the CMB than they evaporate from Hawking Radiation, how does one evaporate at all?  (Pardon my ignorance, I am not a scientist but an engineer.)

Comment: The CMB wiil be colder than stellar mass BHs in roughly $10^{29}$ years, and by then there won't be much starlight warming BHs either. That's a very long time, but it's an eyeblink in comparison to how long it will take for those BHs to fully evaporate. And of course the SMBHs will take even longer.